Public and private API definitions in Spring Cloud Gateway: static or database-driven?
I am using Spring Cloud Gateway and have implemented a RouteValidator class to secure my APIs. Currently, I define the public and private APIs statically in the code, like this:
public static final List<String> openApiEndpoints = List.of(
    "/register",
    "/login",
);

For role-based access control, I also use a static mapping like this:
private static final Map<String, List<String>> roleEndpointMapping = Map.of(
    "/admin/**",List.of("ADMIN_ROLE"),
    "/user/**", List.of("ADMIN_ROLE", "USER_ROLE"),
    "/public/**", List.of("PUBLIC_ROLE")
);

However, I’m looking for a more dynamic and scalable solution.
One idea is to fetch these configurations from a database, but I'm unsure about the best approach for this. My questions are:

Should the API Gateway itself connect to the database? Should it fetch this information directly on each request?
Or should another microservice provide this data? For instance, an "authorization" or "configuration" service could handle this.

If the second approach is better, how should the API Gateway communicate with this microservice?
In short, what would be a recommended architecture for managing public/private API definitions dynamically in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Is RouteDefinitionRepository what you want?
There are two built-in implementations, which are RedisRouteDefinitionRepository  and InMemoryRouteDefinitionRepository .

@DingHao Thank you for your suggestion! Currently, my API Gateway fetches role and endpoint mappings from an AUTH-SERVICE using WebClient, stores them in memory, and uses this for dynamic role-based access control. Public endpoints are managed via a static list.
Would using RouteDefinitionRepository (e.g., Redis or InMemory) be a better approach for managing dynamic routes and access control? If so, how would you recommend integrating it with this setup? I’d appreciate your insights
